# How to find out which method is called by an operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, magic-methods

I want to know which method is called by the `[]` operator. I know it is `__getitem__`, but I wonder how one could figure this out programmatically (without looking it up in some docs). I imagine something like the below, but somehow easier:

```
from unittest import mock

class MyList(list):  # needed because list attributes are read-only
    pass

names = {}
for attrname in list.__dict__.keys():
    try:
        with mock.patch(f"__main__.MyList.{attrname}"):
            l = MyList([1])
            _ = l[0]
            call_count = l.__getattribute__(attrname).call_count
            if call_count > 0:
                names[attrname] = call_count 
    except Exception as e:
        pass

print(names)
```